# Prevent SVG SMIL click animation from running more than once

Tags: html, svg

I have the following SVG I animate with SMIL - this works fine on click, but will be rerun on repeating clicks - how can I prevent this? I want it to only run once and then do nothing on another click!

```
<g id="Gruppe_703" data-name="Gruppe 703" transform="translate(0 -185)" opacity="0">

    <animateTransform
        attributeName="transform"
        attributeType="XML"
        type="translate"
        from="0 -185"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="0.1s"
        begin="Gruppe_589.click"
        fill="freeze"/>

</g>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the pointer-events property to none at the end of the animation then further mouse clicks are ignored.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="1s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"/>
   <set
        attributeName="pointer-events"
        to="none"
        begin="at.end"/>
 </polygon>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. It's a great idea to use "pointer-events ="none" at the end point of the animation!

Answer (score 3):

Consider other options to prevent re-animation after a click:

[**restart = "whenNotActive"**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart)

> This value indicates that the animation can only be restarted when it
> is not active (i.e. after the active end). Attempts to restart the
> animation during its active duration are ignored.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="3s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
   
 </polygon>

</svg>
```

[**restart = "never"**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart)

> This value indicates that the animation cannot be restarted for the
> time the document is loaded.

In other words, the animation fires only once, it cannot be restarted.
The animation can only be started again after reloading the document.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="3s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="never"/>
 </polygon>
</svg>
```